# How could scientists produce accurate chemical structures before they could capture images of molecules?

Tags: structural-formula, history-of-chemistry

How were scientists able to produce these accurate structural diagrams long before scientists were able to capture images of the actual molecules?

Reference: [Scientists capture first images of molecules before and after reaction](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/05/130530142007.htm)

Comment: It should be noted that those molecules are being resolved at low resolution (we see 7 units in a molecule with 40 atoms) -- so much of the molecular structure is still being inferred the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Technically, this is a duplicate of another question, but the answers to that question only address chemical composition rather than structure...so I wouldn't say this is a true duplicate. Anyway, the first step to determining structure is to determine composition, so this other question provides part of the answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-were-elements-and-molecular-formulae-determined-in-the-old-days?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They ran chemical reactions on the molecule and identified the fragments.  Then like a jigsaw puzzle, using additional information derived from other chemical reactions, they pieced the molecule back together.  Some Nobel prizes were awarded for such structure determinations.